# loading same jquery code in multiple jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have jquery datepicker in my document a few times, dependent on which "< span >" is called.

If I have datepicker more than 1 time in the document, it doesn't load at all.

How do I overcome this problem?

`<span id="subname1-1" class="step">`
TITLE

```
            <div id="datepicker"></div>

            <div id="appt_container">
            <div class="appt"><input onFocus="blur();" class="appt_date" id="day_selected"></div>
                    <div style="width: 200px;"><a href="newlink1" id="newlink1" class="select_item">ITEM</a></div>
                    <div style="width: 200px;"><a href="newlink2" id="newlink2" class="select_item">ITEM</a></div>
                    <div style="width: 200px;"><a href="newlink3" id="newlink3" class="select_item">ITEM</a></div>

            </div>
                    <input type="hidden" class="link" value="confirmation" />
            </span>
            <span id="subname1-2" class="step">
                    <span class="font_normal_07em_black">TITLE</span><br />

            <div id="datepicker"></div>

            <div id="appt_container">
            <div class="appt"><input onFocus="blur();" class="appt_date" id="day_selected"></div>

                    <div style="width: 200px;"><a href="newlink1" id="newlink1" class="select_item">ITEM</a></div>
                    <div style="width: 200px;"><a href="newlink2" id="newlink2" class="select_item">ITEM</a></div>
                    <div style="width: 200px;"><a href="newlink3" id="newlink3" class="select_item">ITEM</a></div>
                    <input type="hidden" class="link" value="confirmation" />
            </span>
```

`

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: Are you using Ajax to load a new tab? And the document.ready ?

Comment: Not using ajax.  What do you mean by document.ready?  I believe that is in my < head > < /head >

Comment: @Thorsten 
I am just using `<div id="datepicker"></div>` in different "SPAN"
Each span has different content, and is loaded according to which link was selected beforehand.

Comment: Ok, part of the code.  The datepicker will be in document up to many times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have multiple IDs named "datepicker" on your site.

You must not use an ID more than once.

Rewrite your code to use a class:

```
<div class="datepicker">
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Comment: I do have a problem, the input that shows todays date does not show the date of today's date again properly once this form is submitted through jquery.
`<input onFocus="blur();" class="day_selected">`

Comment: Please add your JS Code as well